# Filtering an availability zone from a remote state's list of subnets?

Tags: terraform

I'm currently in the process of setting up an MSK cluster in Terraform. The availability zone us-east-1e will not work with MSK. My list is being generated in a remote state file. Would it be possible to call that list and filter out the subnets for us-east-1e without modifying the original file?

```
resource "aws_msk_cluster" "example" {
  cluster_name           = "msk-cluster-${var.env}"
  kafka_version          = "2.2.1"
  number_of_broker_nodes = 3

  broker_node_group_info {
    instance_type   = "kafka.m5.large"
    ebs_volume_size = "1000"
    client_subnets  = [ "${data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.public_subnet_ids}" ] // needs to exclude us-east-1e
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Terraform 0.12 or higher, you can use a [for-expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions):

```
client_subnets = [for az in data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.public_subnet_ids: az if az != "us-east-1e"]
```

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks!

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with Terraform 0.11.

Comment: Then what about `client_subnets = ["${compact(split(',', replace(join(',', data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.public_subnet_ids), 'us-east-1e', '')))}"]`? (haven't tested it yet)